# JDBC Multi-Row INSERT peformance is horrible

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-jdbc, rds

Why would I be getting linear performance on increasing batch sizes for this Spring JDBC implementation.  Is there some further tuning I might do (apart from an explain, indice review, and database settings tuning)?  I should mention I am running this code against a `MySQL 5.6` instance hosted on an AWS `db.r3.2xlarge` class RDS server.

```
@Repository
public class JdbcRatePlanLevelCostPriceLogRepository implements Insertable<RatePlanLevelCostPriceLog> {

@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

private static final String INSERT_STATEMENT = InsertStatementBuilder.build();

@Override
public RatePlanLevelCostPriceLog insert(RatePlanLevelCostPriceLog entity) {
    jdbcTemplate.execute(INSERT_STATEMENT, new SingleCallbackImpl(entity));
    return entity;
}

@Override
public List<RatePlanLevelCostPriceLog> insert(List<RatePlanLevelCostPriceLog> entities) {
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(INSERT_STATEMENT, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
            RatePlanLevelCostPriceLog entity = entities.get(i);
            PreparedStatementTranslator.translate(ps, entity);
        }

        @Override
        public int getBatchSize() {
            return entities.size();
        }
    });
    return entities;
}

private static class InsertStatementBuilder {

    static String build() {
        StringBuffer colsBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer valuesBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        colsBuffer.append("INSERT INTO rate_plan_level_cost_price_log(");
        valuesBuffer.append("VALUES (");
        // handle the @NotNull fields
        colsBuffer.append("hotel_id");
        colsBuffer.append(",rate_plan_id");
        colsBuffer.append(",stay_date");
        colsBuffer.append(",rate_plan_level");
        colsBuffer.append(",person_count");
        colsBuffer.append(",length_of_stay_in_days");
        colsBuffer.append(",rpcp_log_seq_num");
        colsBuffer.append(",log_action_type_id");
        colsBuffer.append(",active_status_type_id");
        colsBuffer.append(",supplier_update_date");
        colsBuffer.append(",create_date");
        colsBuffer.append(",supplier_update_tpid");
        colsBuffer.append(",supplier_update_tuid");
        colsBuffer.append(",supplier_log_seq_num");
        // handle the optional fields
        colsBuffer.append(",cost_amount");
        colsBuffer.append(",cost_code");
        colsBuffer.append(",price_amount");
        colsBuffer.append(",change_request_id");
        colsBuffer.append(",change_request_id_old");
        colsBuffer.append(",lar_amount");
        colsBuffer.append(",lar_margin_amount");
        colsBuffer.append(",lar_taxes_and_fees_amount");
        valuesBuffer.append("?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?");
        colsBuffer.append(")");
        valuesBuffer.append(")");
        return String.join(" ", colsBuffer.toString(), valuesBuffer.toString());
    }
}

private static class PreparedStatementTranslator {

    static void translate(PreparedStatement ps, RatePlanLevelCostPriceLog entity) throws SQLException {
        int i = 0;
        // handle the @NotNull fields
        ps.setInt(++i, entity.getHotelId());
        ps.setInt(++i, entity.getRatePlanId());
        ps.setTimestamp(++i, new Timestamp(entity.getStayDate().getTime()));
        ps.setInt(++i, entity.getRatePlanLevel());
        ps.setInt(++i, entity.getPersonCount());
        ps.setInt(++i, entity.getLengthOfStayInDays());
        ps.setInt(++i, entity.getRpcpLogSeqNum());
        ps.setInt(++i, entity.getLogActionTypeId());
        ps.setInt(++i, entity.getActiveStatusTypeId());
        ps.setTimestamp(++i, new Timestamp(entity.getSupplierUpdateDate().getTime()));
        ps.setTimestamp(++i, new Timestamp(entity.getCreateDate().getTime()));
        ps.setInt(++i, entity.getSupplierUpdateTpid());
        ps.setInt(++i, entity.getSupplierUpdateTuid());
        ps.setInt(++i, entity.getSupplierLogSeqNum());
        // handle the optional fields
        if (entity.getCostAmount() != null) {
            ps.setDouble(++i, entity.getCostAmount());
        } else {
            ps.setNull(++i, Types.DOUBLE);
        }
        if (entity.getCostCode() != null) {
            ps.setString(++i, entity.getCostCode());
        } else {
            ps.setNull(++i, Types.VARCHAR);
        }
        if (entity.getPriceAmount() != null) {
            ps.setDouble(++i, entity.getPriceAmount());
        } else {
            ps.setNull(++i, Types.DOUBLE);
        }
        if (entity.getChangeRequestId() != null) {
            ps.setInt(++i, entity.getChangeRequestId());
        } else {
            ps.setNull(++i, Types.INTEGER);
        }
        if (entity.getChangeRequestIdOld() != null) {
            ps.setInt(++i, entity.getChangeRequestIdOld());
        } else {
            ps.setNull(++i, Types.INTEGER);
        }
        if (entity.getLarAmount() != null) {
            ps.setDouble(++i, entity.getLarAmount());
        } else {
            ps.setNull(++i, Types.DOUBLE);
        }
        if (entity.getLarMarginAmount() != null) {
            ps.setDouble(++i, entity.getLarMarginAmount());
        } else {
            ps.setNull(++i, Types.DOUBLE);
        }
        if (entity.getLarTaxesAndFeesAmount() != null) {
            ps.setDouble(++i, entity.getLarTaxesAndFeesAmount());
        } else {
            ps.setNull(++i, Types.DOUBLE);
        }
    }

}

private class SingleCallbackImpl implements PreparedStatementCallback<Boolean> {

    private final RatePlanLevelCostPriceLog entity;

    SingleCallbackImpl(RatePlanLevelCostPriceLog entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException,
                    DataAccessException {
        PreparedStatementTranslator.translate(ps, entity);
        return ps.execute();
    }

}

}
```

It takes  `~250 ms` to execute a single record insert and then `N * 250 ms` for batches of `N`.

Comment: I've seen statements like this `INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);`  I guess I could manufacture one from elements in list; it just wouldn't be a `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: You can make them prepared statements, you just have to carefully track the parameters' positions/names.

Comment: Make sure you have a single transaction and make sure that you driver supports batch processing if not each query is executed as is. See also [this](http://blog.javabien.net/2014/05/14/mysql-and-jdbc-batch-inserts/) which explains that default settings basically disable batch statements for MySQL.